# Adding a checkbox to every cell in the tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've already made a table view which allows the user to add tasks to the table view, but now I need to add a checkbox in front of each task, so that the user can select which tasks she/he wants to send to an other viewController.

After I googled it, I realized that there is no checkBox or radioButton in swift, I should create my own "boxChecked.png" and "boxUnchecked.png",

Here is a piece of my code which gives me an error:

```
if (selectedIndex == indexPath) {
    cell.radioButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "boxChecked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
} else {
    cell.radioButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "boxUnchecked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

The error it gives me is:

> 'UITableViewCell?' does not have a member named 'radiobutton'

even though I tried creating a class named TableViewCell which is a subclass of UITableViewCell, and declared the variable *radioButton* in it like:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var radioButton: UIButton!
```

but it still didn't work.

Here is the code of *func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)*:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    
    if (selectedIndex == indexPath) {
        cell.radioButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "boxChecked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        cell.radioButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "boxUnchecked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Right
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textAlignment = .Left
    cell.textLabel?.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].score

    return cell
    
    //let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Default")
   // cell.textLabel?.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
   // cell.detailTextLabel?.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desc
   //return cell
}
```

Comment: You need cast cell to TableViewCell, show all code of     
`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`
method

Comment: I updated my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? TableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = TableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    }
    if (selectedIndex == indexPath) {
        cell!.radioButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "boxChecked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        cell!.radioButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "boxUnchecked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    cell!.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Right
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.textAlignment = .Left

    cell!.textLabel?.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].score
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error on the second line " TableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, " and says : use of undeclared type 'TableViewCell'

Comment: @NABS, are you sure that you did created class TableViewCell as UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: Yes I did, but then i deleted it because i kept getting the same error above

Comment: @AlexanderGrebenshikov This isn't how you should create table view cells. You should register them first and then deque them to take advantage of cell re-use instead of creating a new one each time...

Comment: @Remover you're right, i am trying modify original code

Comment: tableView doesn't know anything about the `"cell"` reuse identifer. Also, I'm not a Swift guru, but it seems to me, that the compile time type of `var cell` will be `UITableViewCell` (because initially we get it from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` without any type casts), so (I might be wrong) this: `cell!.radioButton?` won't compile because `UITableViewCell` doesn't include `radioButton`.

Comment: @FreeNickname you're right about dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier type, i fix it. But tableView now about `"cell"` reuse identifer after `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returning cell created by `TableViewCell(style: reuseIdentifier)`.

Sorry for my english, quite difficult to respond constructively

Comment: @AlexanderGrebenshikov, oh, right, my bad, sorry. P.S. Indeed, it would be more convenient for us to talk in Russian :) It's a pity it wouldn't be good for the community :) Но я Вас понял, так что не переживайте :)

Comment: So what do i have to do know to make it work? I mean, should I create a vaiable cell, and is it wrong that I'm trying to use two .png pictures to have this feature done?

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiatie your custom table view cell like this if you're using Interface Builder:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IdentifierInInterfaceBuilder") as? MyCustomTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    return cell
}
```

Set up your cell in IB like this:

[image: Custom cell]

[image: Identifier]

---

I think your approach might be more difficult than necessary. When you have a UITableViewCell the standard (not custom ones) allow for text and an image. If you set the image through Interface Builder (or programmatically) you can set a normal and a **highlighted** image value. This will use the selected image whenever the cell is selected and the other when it isn't.

This also means now that a regular selection action will be enough, making the whole table view cell a hotspot and you can very simply get the selected cells and the events for selecting and unselecting through the built-in delegates and functions.

For more complex approaches not falling within the possibilities of a Plain UITableViewCell you can use the highlighted value for a UIImageView and change it after either selecting or when you load it at first.

```
class ExampleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var checkMark: UIImageView?

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        checkMark?.highlighted = selected
    }
}
```

Do you see how little code it requires and how it just works with the flow of the way the UITableView works?

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't get how we declared the variable UIImageView and where it's located exactly? do i have to declare two image views, one is checked and the other unchecked?

Comment: @IBOutlet means Interface Builder Outlet. So you have your UITableView in Interface Builder and you can add a table view cell prototype in it. This prototype can have a custom class and if you add a UIImageView inside that prototype cell and connect it to the IBOutlet you can manipulate that image via the code in your custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `UITableView`. It uses cells to display content. There is one built-in default implementation of a cell: `UITableViewCell`. In order to customize `UITableViewCell` appearance, we create custom cells like you did  with the `TableViewCell` class. Bring it back if you deleted it.

`UITableView` reuses cells for efficiency. When the cell goes off screen, it is saved, and when the table view needs the same kind of cell later, it doesn't recreate it every time. It takes it from its cache (if it is not empty).

There may be several different kinds of cells in a table view (e.g. user info cell, tasks cells, etc.). In order to understand, what kind of cell the table view should create/get from cache, `reuseIdentifer` is used. `reuseIdentifer` denotes a kind of cell. So, there should be some way to tell the `tableView`, that when we request a `"RadioButtonCell"` (for instance), we want it to create a cell with class `TableViewCell` (your custom subclass).

There are several ways to do that. It can be done via storyboards, it can be done through code. If your cell has a `xib` (interface file) associated with it, you can do it using

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)), forCellReuseIdentifier: "RadioButtonCell")
```

If you didn't create an interface file for it, you can do it using

```
tableView.registerClass(..., forCellReuseIdentifier: ...)
```

method.

You can register nibs once (for instance, inside viewDidLoad).
Then later in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you do:

```
var cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RadioButtonCell)
```

and customize this cell as you did in your question.

Comment: Where should I put  :"tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)), forCellReuseIdentifier: "RadioButtonCell")" ?

Comment: I mean, inside tableView function, or on a new line independently?

Comment: I tried putting it inside the tableView and it gives me an error as well as when i put it outside that function

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed the type of the `UITableViewCell` using the interface builder to your custom `UITableViewCell`

> Select your cell > Select the Identity Inspector in the right pane >
>   change the class to your custom UITableViewCell class name.

You need also to connect the check button view with the outlet in your custom class.

You also need to add 2 UILabels one for the title and one for the details and connect them too.

Comment: I already have the labels which have the titles, they adding and removing tasks is working as well, except the select feature still doesn't work